# Footer is in the middle of an iFrame component. How can I push it to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, iframe, footer, sticky-footer

I'm trying to make a footer that is pushed to the bottom of the page, and it works everywhere except on the homepage where I've put an iFrame with a YouTube video in it. Once I remove the iFrame (that isn't an option, I just tried for testing), it is pushed to the bottom. When the iFrame is present, the footer is in the middle of it. I'm using Bootstrap-Vue, Bootstrap 5, and Vue.js.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <footer id="footer" class="bg-dark text-light text-center text-sm-center p-4 align-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="d-lg-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div>
            <p style="color: gray" class="lead my-4">{{text}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: "Footer",
  props: {
    text: String
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

This the Footer component code.

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <Header image="kabul_map.jpg" title="Kabul" :introduction="introduction"></Header>
        <AboutKabulVideo :url="url" :text="videoText" title="Find Out More About Kabul"></AboutKabulVideo>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import Header from "@/components/Header";
    import AboutKabulVideo from "@/components/AboutKabulVideo";
    
    export default {
      // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
      name: "Home",
      components: {
        Header,
        AboutKabulVideo,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          introduction: "Kabul is the capital city of Afghanistan. The settlement Kabul has existed for about 3,500 years.",
          url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/WRo_-ZXrSIc",
          videoText: "Kabul is indeed a beautiful place, or at least it was before the Taliban takeover. Take a look at this video to find out more about life in Kabul since Taliban takeover of Afghanistan."
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    </style>
```

This is the Home page component code.

```
<template>
  <section class="bg-light text-light p-5 text-center text-sm-start align-items-start">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="align-items-start justify-content-start">
        <div>
          <h1 class="header-title">{{title.toUpperCase()}}</h1>
          <p class="lead my-4">{{text}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="iframe-container">
          <iframe class="responsive-iframe" :src="url"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AboutKabulVideo",
  props: {
    text: String,
    url: String,
    title: String
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  p, h1 {
    color: black;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio (divide 9 by 16 = 0.5625) */
  }

  /* Then style the iframe to fit in the container div with full height and width */
  .responsive-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
</style>
```

And this is the iFrame component code.

I've tried numerous ways to fix this, but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position absolute of '#footer' to position relative.

Comment: I wouldn't use absolute to position a footer at the bottom of the page. The content itself just need to use flex grow so it always take full screen space.
As seen here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-grow

Comment: I tried using position relative and now it wasn't in the middle of the iframe, but on other pages, it wasn't at the bottom, so I just removed it, it wasn't really necessary.